# PHONEGAPのプラグインの導入

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

カメラ機能のあるiPadアプリをPhonegapで作ろうとして、プラグインがないことに気づきました。

```
cd /Users/tcmc/Documents/iOSApp/sample4
phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

こう入力すると下記のように表示されました。

```
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.file" via plugin registry
Installing "org.apache.cordova.file" for ios
```

xcodeで実行したところエラーになりました

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 
'/Users/tcmc/Documents/iOSApp/sample4/platforms/ios/sample4/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.m'
```

よくみたらそれらしいファイルが`/Users/tcmc/Documents/iOSApp/sample4/platforms/ios/sample4/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/src/ios/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.m`にあります。
`org.apache.cordova.camera/src/ios/`の中身を`org.apache.cordova.camera`にコピーしたところ一応エラーは無くなりましたが警告がでておりカメラは動作しません

```
/Users/tcmc/Documents/iOSApp/sample4/platforms/ios/sample4/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/CDVLocalFilesystem.m:438:93: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'
```

導入の方法が間違っているのでしょうか？